# Top border is not working with cutting edges

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

i was trying to make menu buttons with cutting edges, i want to give it a top border but it is not working at all, when i give it a border it come out a little to the left side.. please help
each menu button have different color, i want to make it top boder RED but it is not working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9AsL/)
html

CSS

```
.btncol1 {
    background-color: #8cc63e;
}
.btncol2 {
    background-color: #aadcf3;
}
.btncol3 {
    background-color: #87868e;
}
.btncol4 {
    background-color: #c47269;
}
.btncol5 {
    background-color: #8cc63e;
}
.button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.button:before {
    content:'';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid White;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
.button {
    height: 55px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j9AsL/1/)?

Comment: @harry You just beat me. That should be answer. :)

Comment: @redditor: Yep, if that is what OP wanted :) I don't know if we understood the question correctly, so waiting to add it as answer.

Comment: @harry Agreed, it was a weirdly worded question I had to view the example to understand but I'm pretty sure you've nailed it with your fiddle.

Comment: exactly that what i mean  @Harry you have made my life

Comment: Sorry but it is not working if i do it like border-top: 3px solid red;

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: Like I have mentioned in my answer, when you increase the border-width, you have to adjust the `margin-top` of the `:before` element also. Increase it also by 2px to -17px and it would work like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9AsL/2/).

Comment: @Harry: thanks alot, but please don't get me wrong am totally new to these things, what if we want to have a little white space between this red top and div? is this possible?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: No worries mate. But that white space would be a little more complex to achieve. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border` is going out a bit to the left side because the red border is for the whole `div` and  the cutting edge is positioned on top of the `div` by using CSS.

Now since you are applying the red border, you have to move the position of the `:before` pseudo-element a bit higher for the red border to become invisible and get positioned under the cutting edge.

```
.button {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.button:before {
    content:'';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid White;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: -15px; /* This was changed */
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what if i want to make it as border-top: 3px solid red; or higher pixels.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: For the white-space between the red border and the div, you can refer to this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/j9AsL/5/). This is very hackish, so I wouldn't suggest its usage. But if you have no other choice, then you can try this way. And just a comment on your HTML, avoid adding `<p>` tags inside `<a>`.